# Efficiency of the command pmvnorm in R

Tags: r, algorithms, multivariate-normal-distribution, efficiency

Let $X_1,\,X_2,\ldots,\,X_n$ be $n$ independent random variables, where $X_i\sim\text{N}(\mu_i,\,\sigma_i^2)$, for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,\,n\}$. Consider the $n$-dimensional random vector
$$\boldsymbol{Y}_n=\left(X_1,\,X_1+X_2,\ldots,\,X_1+\cdots+X_n\right)^T$$
I learned that $\boldsymbol{Y}_n$ follows a $n$-dimensional normal distribution, with 
$$\mathbb{E}(\boldsymbol{Y}_n)=\left(\mu_1,\,\mu_1+\mu_2,\ldots,\,\mu_1+\cdots+\mu_n\right)^T$$
and the covariance matrix of $\boldsymbol{Y}_n$ is a $n\times n$ matrix $[a_{i,\,j}]$ such that
$$a_{i,\,j}=\sum_{k=1}^{\min\{i,\,j\}}\sigma^2_k$$
When computing the joint cumulative distribution function of $\boldsymbol{Y}_n$ in ${\tt R}$-software, I realized that the command ${\tt pmvnorm}$ becomes less efficient as $n$ increases (e.g., when $n=3000$).

The following is the R-code I am using:

```
library(mvtnorm)

n <- 3000
Mean_X <- runif(n, min = -20, max = 20)
Var_X <- rexp(n, rate = 50)
CumSum_Var_X <- cumsum(Var_X)

Mean_Y <- cumsum(Mean_X)
Var_Y <- matrix(Var_X[1], nrow = 1, ncol = n)
for(k in 2:n) Var_Y <- rbind(Var_Y, c(CumSum_Var_X[1:k], rep(CumSum_Var_X[k], n - k)))

y <- runif(n, min = -20, max = 20)
# Joint cumulative distribution function of Yn, evaluated in y.
Pr <- pmvnorm(upper = y, mean = Mean_Y, sigma = Var_Y)
```

**Question:** I was wondering if you could tell me how to compute the joint cumulative distribution function of $\boldsymbol{Y}_n$ in ${\tt R}$-software in a more efficient way than ${\tt pmvnorm}$ for large values of $n$.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: R demands everything reside in memory.  Likely that it is memory issues that are causing the problem.

Comment: What is the full code you are currently using?

Comment: Hi @Greenparker. I included the R-code I am using. I will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, @aginensky. I think so. However, I tried to find (with no success) any algorithm to make more efficient computations.

Comment: @Student1981 Do you want a way to improve the whole code, or are you just interested in the pmvnorm? Because your most expensive step seems to be the making of Var_Y, which can be made much faster. Also, pmvnorm, can't deal with n larger than 1000.

Comment: I am interested in the pmvnorm command only.

Comment: You can view $(Y_m)_{m\le n}$ as a realisation of an inhomogeneous Markov chain (or time changed Brownian motion if you prefer).  Use the Markov property to recursively calculate the path probability without computing the whole covariance matrix.

Comment: Hi @P.Windridge. Thanks for your idea. I will have a try.

Comment: You're welcome.  Just to check, do you really need the distribution function (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(Y_1 < a_1, \ldots, Y_n < a_n)$ ) or would the density (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(Y_1 \in da_1, \ldots, Y_n \in da_n)$) suffice for your application?

Comment: I believe I understood your notation. One defines the stochastic process $\{Y_1,\,Y_2,\,Y_3,\ldots\}$ such that $Y_1=X_1$ and $Y_n=Y_{n-1}+X_n$, for all $n\in\{2,\,3,\,4,\ldots\}$. Thus, $\{Y_n:\,n\in\{1,\,2,\,3,\,4,\ldots\}\}$ defines a non-homogeneous, discrete-time Markov Chain. Is that correct?

Comment: @ OP there are various packages for doing parallel computation in R.  That may help.  In addition, there are some packages (data.table comes to mind) that implement pointers.  Such a package would greatly decrease memory usage.  It's possible that can be done in the context of your issue.

Comment: Hi, @P.Windridge. I followed your approach and I solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In general, *any* R operation will become less efficient as $n$ increases. Especially problematic is that we can't immediately assume any convenient representation of these data, like independence, so the covariance matrix must be supplied explicitly in the form of an $n \times n$ matrix. Complicating matters further is that you are basically calling for the evaluation of an $n$-dimensional integral.

Inspecting the workhorse code for `pmvnorm` reveals a bit more insight to the problem. Much work has gone into developing better algorithms. See [here](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/papers/mvtcmpn.pdf) from the package author. The approach used here is an adaptation of MCMC integration by using what he calls "quasi" random samples. It is an iterative, sampling based procedure that has an unproven complexity, but some intuition can be gained from Figure 3.

To improve computation, pre-process your data. If $\Sigma$ is block diagonal or approximately block diagonal, parse the problem into multiple smaller problems with smaller $n$.

Comment: Thanks, @AdamO, for sharing your perspective of the problem.

Comment: @Student1981 I admit i haven't done much research in the area. However, I feel confident that it is an open problem to find more efficient multivariate normal implementations, that is if the manuscript I linked is to be trusted. Not a perspective, at least not in the subjective sense.

Comment: One might even go further and say that the whole concept of "efficiency" here is about the *rate* at which the computation becomes longer as $n$ increases (i.e., we can't even say that it is less efficient as $n$ increases, so much as we can saay it *takes longer* as $n$ increases).